# Typescript: how to retrieve Class name?

Tags: angular, typescript, class, classname

In typescript how do you retrieve Class name from within the Class itself?

For example, given the following code:

```js
export class SomeRandomName extends AbstractSomething<SomeType> implements OnDestroy {

  className = 'SomeRandomName';
```

is there a way to automatically assign to `className` variable the name of the class `SomeRandomName`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: instanceOfSomeRandomName.constructor.name

Comment: @enno.void thank you; however, one needs to instantiate a class object first and then assign the class name through `instanceOfSomeRandomName.constructor.name`. Can I assign it from within the Class itself?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do this:

```js
export class SomeRandomName extends AbstractSomething<SomeType> implements OnDestroy {
      getName() {
        return (this as any).constructor.name;
      }
}
```

Comment: Very nice, thanks

Answer (score 2):

A TypeScript class is just an ES6 class. You can get the name of the class as a string from `.constructor.name`

```
class Foo {}

const foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo.constructor.name); // Foo
```

Comment: Thank you; is there a way to assign the class name from within the class itself and not through a class instance, e.g. without creating a class object?

Comment: I expect Andrew means: from within the Constructor itself; For the record I have not found a way to access the class prototype from within its own Constructor. But would be pleased if someone finds a way. (I often to this to name instances from within the constructor, and so far it seems to require making a string copy of the class name; seems ugly & not DRY)